# "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"

Tags: python, indentation

I'm trying to create an application in Python 3.2 and I use tabs all the time for indentation, but even the editor changes some of them into spaces and then print out "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" when I try to run the program.

How can I change the spaces into tabs? It's driving me crazy.

```
import random

attraktioner = ["frittfall","bergodalbana","spökhuset"]


class Nojesfalt:
    def __init__(self, attraktion):
        self.val = attraktion
        self.langd = 0
        self.alder = 0


#längdgräns för fritt fall
    def langdgrans(self):
        print("")
        self.langd = int(input("Hur lång är du i cm? "))
        if self.langd < 140:
            print("tyvärr, du är för kort, prova något annat")
            return 0
        elif self.langd >= 140:
            print("håll dig hatten, nu åker vi!")
            print(" ")
            return 1

#åldersgräns för spökhuset
    def aldersgrans(self):
        print("")
        self.alder = int(input("Hur gammal är du? "))
        if self.alder < 10:
            print("tyvärr, du är för ung, prova något annat")
            return 0
        elif self.alder >= 10:
            print("Gå in om du törs!")
            print(" ")
            return 1


#åker attraktion frittfall lr bergodalbana
        def aka(self):
                print("")
        print(self.val)
        tal = random.randint(0,100)
        if tal < 20:
            print("åkturen gick åt skogen, bättre lycka nästa gång")
        elif tal >= 20:
            print("jabbadabbbadoooooooo")
            return 1

#går i spökhuset
        def aka1(self):
                print("")
        print(self.val)
        tal = random.randint(0,100)
        if tal < 20:
            print("du är omringad av spöken och kan inte fortsätta")            return 0
        elif tal >= 20:
            print("Buhuuuuuu, buuuhuuuu")
            return 1

#programkod
print("Välkommen till nöjesfältet, vad vill du göra?")
print(" ")

while 1:
    vald_attr = input("Vad vill du göra?\n1. frittfall\n2. bergodalbana\n3. spökhuset\n4. Avsluta\n")
    if vald_attr == "1":
        val = Nojesfalt(attraktioner[0])
        if val.langdgrans() == 1:
            val.aka()
    elif vald_attr == "2":
        val = Nojesfalt(attraktioner[1])
        val.aka()
    elif vald_attr == "3":
        val = Nojesfalt(attraktioner[2])
        if val.aldersgrans() == 1:
            val.aka1()
    elif vald_attr == "4":
        break
```

Comment: That's an issue with your code editor, not really with python.  You should change your question to reflect that and mention what editor you are using.

Comment: How you change this depends on your editor. I'm not sure this is even on-topic here, it might be a question for superuser.

Comment: The subject has very little to do with the actual question asked. There are better phrased questions on SO, both covering `TabError` and editor configuration. Ideally this entire question should be removed, but being too old and to active that's likely not an option. How can the situation be improved so that more useful answers are presented, before these ones, to those coming for a solution to what's actually in the title?

Comment: Given the discussion, I agree that this isn't a good quality question. People who come here are going to want to understand the topic more generally, so I linked it as a duplicate to the community-driven, artificial canonical that was deliberately made to be broad enough to cover problems with indentation generally.

Answer (score 413):

Don't use tabs.

1. Set your editor to use 4 **spaces** for indentation.
2. Make a search and replace to replace all tabs with 4 spaces.
3. Make sure your editor is set to **display** tabs as 8 spaces.

Note: The reason for 8 spaces for tabs is so that you immediately notice when tabs have been inserted unintentionally - such as when copying and pasting from example code that uses tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: Is there any reasoning behind these dogmas?

Comment: @RocketR: The answer is for Python. If you use tabs only, you get an 8-space indentation, unless you expand tabs to something else than 8 spaces, in which case it will look bad on other editors. If you mix tabs and spaces, it may break (see question) or look broken if you have other than 8-space expansion of tabs. In summary: Using tabs for indentation is incredibly bad. **Never do that ever** (except for languages/file formats that require it). The end.

Comment: @RocketR Python has Pep8, a document which lists "good python style" which explicitly states that 4 spaces is the accepted form on indentation.

Comment: [Link to relevant PEP 8 section on "Tabs vs Spaces"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) spoiler: the first line is **"Spaces are the preferred indentation method."**

Comment: For vim: `set tabstop=8 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=4 smarttab` then `%s/\t/    /g`

Comment: If the goal is to *immediately notice* tabs, then might I suggest using a value that *isn't a multiple of* 4 spaces? Then things will visually fail to align, rather than simply being at the wrong level of indentation.

Comment: this is wack dude

Comment: It is weird that [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29) went with TABs. [TABs are evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBWAP_8zxaM&t=8m49s)

Answer (score 233):

#### For [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) users

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or menu *View* → *Command Palette*.

Type:

>Convert Indentation to Spaces

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: If you prefer to work with Tabs, you can convert again the code by repeating the instructions above and typing instead: >Convert Indentation to Tabs

Answer (score 151):

Using the `autopep8` command below fixed it for me:

```
 autopep8 -i my_file.py
```

Documentation for `autopep8` [linked here.](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/)

Comment: it is not working..

Answer (score 50):

With the [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29) editor you can use this:

- Menu *Edit* → *Select All*
- Menu *Format* → *Untabify Region*
- Assuming your editor has replaced 8 spaces with a tab, enter 8 into the input box.
- Hit select, and it fixes the entire document.

Answer (score 41):

When using the [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) editor, I was able to select the segment of my code that was giving me the *inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation* error and select:

Menu *View* → *Indentation* → *convert indentation to spaces*

which resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 26):

It is possible to solve this problem using [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) by replacing <kbd>Tab</kbd>s with four <kbd>Space</kbd>s:

1. Choose *Search* → *Find...* or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
2. Select the *Replace* tab
3. In the box named *Search Mode* choose *Extended(\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...)*
4. In the field *Find what :* write *\t*
5. In the field *Replace with :* press <kbd>Space</kbd> 4 times. Be sure that there is nothing else in this field.
6. Click on the button *Replace All*

[image: How to replace Tabs with Spaces]

Comment: Note that this only works if all tabs are at the beginning of the line (so only used for _indentation_, not for _alignment_). If you used tabs at other positions, replacing them with 4 spaces will likely change your indentation in a wrong way.

Answer (score 18):

Generally, people prefer indenting with space. It's more consistent across editors, resulting in fewer mismatches of this sort. However, you are allowed to indent with tab. It's your choice; however, you should be aware that the standard of 8 spaces per tab is a bit wide.

Concerning your issue, most probably, your editor messed up. To convert tab to space is really editor-dependent.

On Emacs, for example, you can call the method 'untabify'.

On command line, you can use a sed line (adapt the number of spaces to whatever pleases you):

```
   sed -e 's;\t;       ;' < yourFile.py > yourNedFile.py
```

Comment: And if you want to do this with an open file in Vim, you can type the following:

`:%s/\t/    /g`

This replaces each tab character with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) for Python development, you can avoid the error by using the package Anaconda. After installing Anaconda, open your file in Sublime Text, right click on the open spaces → choose *Anaconda* → click on autoformat. *Done*. Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: alternative for sublime text - go to view -> indentation -> covert indentation to spaces

Comment: If you are like me and don't have Anaconda, the comment above me is the quickest fix for Sublime Text users.

Answer (score 10):

#### Sublime Text 3

In [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text), while editing a Python file:

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings - Syntax Specific*:

File *Python.sublime-settings*

```
{
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I recently had the same problem and found out that I just needed to convert the .py file's charset to **UTF-8** as that's the set Python 3 uses.

BTW, I used 4-space tabs all the time, so the problem wasn't caused by them.

Answer (score 8):

What I did when the same error popped up: Select everything (<kbd>Str</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. So nothing was indented anymore. Now go back to the lines you want to have indented, and put it back how you want it.

It worked for me...

Answer (score 5):

##### If you use [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)):

Go to Menu: *Packages* → *WhiteSpace* → *Convert all Tabs to Spaces*

Answer (score 3):

With Python code, anything that needs to be indented in a `.py` file, needs to either all be indented using the tab key, or by spaces. Convention is to use four spaces for an indentation. Most editors have the ability to visually show on the editor whether the code is being indented with spaces or tabs, which helps greatly for debugging. For example, with [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)), going to preferences and then editor you can see the following two options:

[image: Atom editor to show tabs and spaces]

Then if your code is using spaces, you will see small dots where your code is indented:

[image]

And if it is indented using tabs, you will see something like this:

[image]

Now if you noticed, you can see that when using tabs, there are more errors/warnings on the left. This is because of something called [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is basically a uniform style guide for Python, so that all developers mostly code to the same standard and appearance, which helps when trying to understand other peoples' code. It is in PEP 8 which favors the use of spaces to indent rather than tabs. And we can see the editor showing that there is a warning relating to PEP 8 warning code `W191`,

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the indents and then systematically either pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> four times.  This usually happens to me when I have an indent using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and then use the space key in the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is due to your editor limitations/configuration. Some editors provide you of tools to help with the problem by:

1. Converting tabs into spaces

   For example, if you are using Stani's Python editor you can configure it to do it on saving.
2. Converting spaces into tabs

If you are using ActiveState Komodo you have a tool to 'tabify' your code. As others already pointed, this is not a good idea.

Eclipse's Pydev provides functions "Convert tabs to space-tabs" and "Convert space-tabs to tabs".

Answer (score 2):

I use Notepad++ and got this error.

In Notepad++ you will see that both the tab and the four spaces are the same, but when you copy your code to Python [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29) you would see the difference and the line with a tab would have more space before it than the others.

To solve the problem, I just deleted the tab before the line then added four spaces.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution for Sublime Text

My solution to this problem was to open it in the [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE) editor and then the IDLE editor will uncover your problem.

E.g.,

#### Sublime Text

```
while run:

    clock.tick(27)

    milli = clock.tick()
    seconds = milli/1000
    timeForLevel += seconds
    print(timeForLevel)
```

#### IDLE editor

```
while run:

    clock.tick(27)

       milli = clock.tick()
    seconds = milli/1000
    timeForLevel += seconds
    print(timeForLevel)
```

I am not saying that you should only use the IDLE editor. I'm saying that if you get that error you should check the IDLE editor.

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58333676/10897050 by Dulangi_Kanchana 
it is possible to solve it in sublime

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I had to add several code lines to an existing *.py file. In Notepad++ it did not work.

After adding the code lines and saving, I got the same error. When I opened the same file in [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) and added the lines, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I oddly ran into a similar issue with one of my .py files. I simply opened the file in [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) and pressed <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> which correctly formats the file contents in one go.

I suspect I was having trouble because I coded this particular .py file through [JupyterLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Applications) as opposed to my usual choice of [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) or PyCharm and therefore ran into some hidden indentation issues many answers here have alluded to.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Pylint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylint). It will give you a detailed report about how many spaces you need and where.

Answer (score 1):

**The following trick has worked for me:**

1. Copy and paste the code in the Windows **Notepad/Notepad++** application.
2. Then from the Notepad/Notepad++ again select all and **copy** the code
3. **Paste** in my views.py
4. Select all the newly pasted code in the views.py and remove all the tabs by pressing **shift+tab** from the keyboard
5. Now use the tab key again to use the proper **indentation**

Comment: What do you mean by "the notepad"? Windows' [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad)? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

For [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)), [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_%28software%29) users, you can go to *Source* → *Fix indentation*.

Comment: *Source* where? This is one of the [few cases](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) where a screenshot does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your editor doesn't recognize tabs when doing a search and replace (like SciTE), you can paste the code into Word and search using Ctr-H and ^t which finds the tabs which then can be replace with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this using the [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) editor:

1. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Go to the directory where the file is located (`cd <path_to_your_directory>`). Example: `cd /home/vineeshvs/work`.
3. Open the file in Vim (`vim <file_name>`). Example: `vim myfile.txt` .
4. [Optional step] Enable search keyword highlighting in Vim (<kbd>ESC</kbd> `:set hlsearch`)
5. Go to the line where you have this problem (<kbd>Esc</kbd> `:<line_number>`). Ex: `:53` in Vim editor after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> button once.
6. Replace tabs using the required number of spaces in Vim (`:.,$s/\t/<give_as_many_spaces_as_you_want_to_replace_tab>/gc`). Example: Tab will be replaced with four spaces using the following command: `:.,$s/\t/    /gc` after pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button once). This process is interactive.  You may give `y` to replace the tab with spaces and `n` to skip a particular replacement. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> when you are done with the required replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem and I realised that the problem is that I copied code from another Python editor to [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text).

I was working with [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) and then I copied the code into Sublime Text. Apparently when you make specific modifications (like moving code in functions) then indentation gets messy and this is where the problem comes from.

So just stick to one editor. If you do so, then you won't be having any problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### For [Jupyter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) users:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> automatically indents the selection:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While the original question is about self authored code, the search engines lead here for when searching for the title string. It is an error message one might very likely get when attempting to make use of an already existing library or tool.

For those finding their way here when attempting to use someone else’s code: It is a [Python 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_2) vs. [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_3) thing, according to [Tab Error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28326024/1981794) (an answer which also refers to the relevant section of the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Answer (score -1):

I got the same errors but could not figure out what I was doing wrong.

So I fixed it by running auto-indent on my code and allowing the machine to fix my fault.

If anyone is wondering how I did that. 
Simple. 
Go in vim. 
Type in G=gg.

This will automatically fix everything. Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, `tab` does mess up while indenting. One way is to obviously use the `tab` and `backspace` to correctly indent the code.

Another way is to use `space` **4 times** (depending on how much you want to indent).

A weird way that worked for me when nothing else worked, whichever line I getting the error, I `backspaced` that line to the previous line and then pressed `enter`. It automatically indented the line to correct position and I was not getting any error after that.

Hopefully, this should help.