# Why do I get a `TabError` from code that appears to be properly aligned?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation

The following python code throws this error message, and I can't tell why, my tabs seem to be in line:

```
File "test.py", line 12
    pass
       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

```
class eightPuzzle(StateSpace):
    StateSpace.n = 0
    
    def __init__(self, action, gval, state, parent = None):
        StateSpace.__init__(self, action, gval, parent)
        self.state = state

    def successors(self) :
        pass
```

Comment: Did you use tabs for one line, and spaces for the other? You can configure you editor to always use 4 spaces when you tab to be consistent.

Comment: Please format your code with the class declaration in the code block.

Comment: I'm willing to bet, that you didn't indent your instance methods under the class declaration.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is: don't use tabs.

Comment: I tried to fix the post so that it would show the actual tab and space characters that OP had for indentation in the original code; but it appears that Stack Overflow's Markdown renderer will convert tabs to spaces anyway, rendering that impossible.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot mix tabs and spaces, according the [**PEP8 styleguide**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces):

*Spaces are the preferred indentation method.*

*Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is already indented with tabs.*

***Python 3 disallows mixing the use of tabs and spaces for indentation.***

***Python 2 code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively.***

*When invoking the Python 2 command line interpreter with the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options are highly recommended!*

Answer (score -1):

**Using Visual Studio 2019**

I was using tabs but the editor was inserting spaces and it would result in errors.

To avoid  getting the spaces and tabs mixed up , set your preferences

Go to Edit->Advanced->Set Leading Whitespace->Tabs (or Whitespaces)

After I set it to Tabs, my tabs stop being represented as spaces and it worked fine thereafter

Comment: Nothing in the question mentions Visual Studio. You should create your own question (and possibly also answer it) when having a problem with a more specific environment.

Answer (score -1):

For linux nano users:

if your code includes 4 spaces instead of a tab, you should keep using 4 spaces or change all of them to a tab. If you use mixed it gives an error.

Answer (score -2):

open your code in a text editor, highlight all of it (ctr+a) and go to format and select either "Tabify region" or "Untabify region". It'll just make all the indents have the same format.

Comment: My text editor doesn't have a Format menu! And how do you know all editors' indentation commands will make tabs consistent?

Comment: I believe all code editors have some feature like this. It might be called "reindent", "auto indent" or somthing like that.

Comment: I used the leafpad text editor and this is how I was able to fix the error. It will either make your indents be all tabs or all spaces

Answer (score -2):

not using the backspace also is important (especially in the Leafpad editor). If you want to decrease indent, use only `Alt_key + TAB`.

This should be done when you delete a line in a Python code.