# Tab error even though my code looks formatted correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, error-handling, tabs

I'm trying to run some code and it's giving me a tab error. I can't seem to fix it

my code goes like this

```
    if e == "url-open}<":
            eb = input(":")
            ebb = input(":")
            if ebb == ">{>ostar-urllib-html-socket<":
                urllib.request.urlopen(eb)
      
            else:
                print("end syntax needed")
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the full error traceback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tab Error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325553/tab-error-in-python)

Comment: *good looks* isn't everything - tip: use an editor that shows you tabs and spaces (on demand/if you highlight the lines)