# Error: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHwVY.jpg)python 3.4.1 and after coding a simple calculator i got Error inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)

Comment: error comes at  elif user_input == "multi":

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on your ide, you can find the "detab" option on one of the menus. Select the entire script and press detab. Select 4 as your tab length and you'll be alright. As a rule of thumb, don't mix tabs and spaces. Preferably use only whitespace (PEP 8)