# Where do I have a bug in the Python script of The Blender's interpritator?

Tags: python, blender

I have the Python script.
The Blender got me an error after running of the script.
An error have not been undestood by me.
I have wanted to know from you what is the problem.
I uploded the script and the hex code of the file to my message.
Is it possible The Blender 2.78c windows32 have a bug in the python interpritation?
Or could you anwer me where do I have an error?

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "Build the living room",
    "category": "Object",
}


def main(context):
    scene = context.scene


class LivingRoomBuilderOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Living Room Builder Operator"""
    bl_idname = "object.the_living_room_builder"
    bl_label = "Living Room Builder Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    l_width = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Room Width", default=4000, min=1000, max=100000)
    l_height = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Room Height", default=2500, min=1000, max=100000)
    l_lenght = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Room Lenght", default=8000, min=1000, max=100000)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(LivingRoomBuilderOperator.bl_idname)


addon_keymaps = []


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LivingRoomBuilderOperator)

    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager

    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Mode', space_type='EMPTY')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(ObjectCursorArray.bl_idname, 'SPACE', 'PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=True)

        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister():

    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LivingRoomBuilderOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The python file has 4 spaces as an intentation. The file have been saved in UTF-8 with BOM.

The Error message: The script has not executed. The Blender's console is empty. It have just shown what the script has an error and have not shown the text of the error.

The hex array of the file:

```
0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF, 0x69, 0x6D, 0x70, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x74, 0x20, 0x62, 0x70, 0x79, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 
0x0A, 0x62, 0x6C, 0x5F, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x7B, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 
0x20, 0x20, 0x22, 0x6E, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x22, 0x42, 0x75, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x64, 
0x20, 0x74, 0x68, 0x65, 0x20, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x76, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x20, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x6D, 
0x22, 0x2C, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x22, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x67, 0x6F, 0x72, 
0x79, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x22, 0x4F, 0x62, 0x6A, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x22, 0x2C, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x7D, 
0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x28, 0x63, 
0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x29, 0x3A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x73, 0x63, 
0x65, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x2E, 0x73, 0x63, 
0x65, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x63, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x20, 0x4C, 
0x69, 0x76, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x52, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x42, 0x75, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x65, 0x72, 
0x4F, 0x70, 0x65, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x28, 0x62, 0x70, 0x79, 0x2E, 0x74, 0x79, 0x70, 
0x65, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x4F, 0x70, 0x65, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x29, 0x3A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 
0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x4C, 0x69, 0x76, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x20, 0x52, 0x6F, 0x6F, 
0x6D, 0x20, 0x42, 0x75, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x65, 0x72, 0x20, 0x4F, 0x70, 0x65, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 
0x6F, 0x72, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x62, 0x6C, 0x5F, 0x69, 0x64, 
0x6E, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x22, 0x6F, 0x62, 0x6A, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x2E, 0x74, 
0x68, 0x65, 0x5F, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x76, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x5F, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x5F, 0x62, 
0x75, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x65, 0x72, 0x22, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x62, 0x6C, 0x5F, 
0x6C, 0x61, 0x62, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x22, 0x4C, 0x69, 0x76, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x20, 
0x52, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x20, 0x42, 0x75, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x65, 0x72, 0x20, 0x4F, 0x70, 0x65, 
0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x22, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x62, 0x6C, 0x5F, 0x6F, 
0x70, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x73, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x7B, 0x27, 0x52, 0x45, 0x47, 0x49, 0x53, 
0x54, 0x45, 0x52, 0x27, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x27, 0x55, 0x4E, 0x44, 0x4F, 0x27, 0x7D, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 
0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x6C, 0x5F, 0x77, 0x69, 0x64, 0x74, 0x68, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x62, 
0x70, 0x79, 0x2E, 0x70, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x70, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x49, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x50, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x70, 
0x65, 0x72, 0x74, 0x79, 0x28, 0x6E, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x3D, 0x22, 0x52, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x20, 
0x57, 0x69, 0x64, 0x74, 0x68, 0x22, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x61, 0x75, 0x6C, 0x74, 0x3D, 
0x34, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x3D, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x20, 
0x6D, 0x61, 0x78, 0x3D, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
0x20, 0x6C, 0x5F, 0x68, 0x65, 0x69, 0x67, 0x68, 0x74, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x62, 0x70, 0x79, 0x2E, 
0x70, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x70, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x49, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x50, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x70, 0x65, 0x72, 0x74, 
0x79, 0x28, 0x6E, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x3D, 0x22, 0x52, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x20, 0x48, 0x65, 0x69, 
0x67, 0x68, 0x74, 0x22, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x61, 0x75, 0x6C, 0x74, 0x3D, 0x32, 0x35, 
0x30, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x3D, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x61, 
0x78, 0x3D, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x6C, 
0x5F, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x68, 0x74, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x62, 0x70, 0x79, 0x2E, 0x70, 0x72, 
0x6F, 0x70, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x49, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x50, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x70, 0x65, 0x72, 0x74, 0x79, 0x28, 
0x6E, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x3D, 0x22, 0x52, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x20, 0x4C, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x68, 
0x74, 0x22, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x61, 0x75, 0x6C, 0x74, 0x3D, 0x38, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 
0x2C, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x3D, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x78, 0x3D, 
0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x40, 
0x63, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x74, 0x68, 0x6F, 0x64, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
0x20, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x20, 0x70, 0x6F, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x28, 0x63, 0x6C, 0x73, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x63, 
0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x29, 0x3A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
0x20, 0x20, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x75, 0x72, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 
0x2E, 0x61, 0x63, 0x74, 0x69, 0x76, 0x65, 0x5F, 0x6F, 0x62, 0x6A, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x20, 0x69, 
0x73, 0x20, 0x6E, 0x6F, 0x74, 0x20, 0x4E, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 
0x20, 0x20, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x20, 0x65, 0x78, 0x65, 0x63, 0x75, 0x74, 0x65, 0x28, 0x73, 0x65, 
0x6C, 0x66, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x29, 0x3A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 
0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x28, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 
0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x72, 0x65, 
0x74, 0x75, 0x72, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x7B, 0x27, 0x46, 0x49, 0x4E, 0x49, 0x53, 0x48, 0x45, 0x44, 0x27, 
0x7D, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x75, 0x5F, 
0x66, 0x75, 0x6E, 0x63, 0x28, 0x73, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x66, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 
0x78, 0x74, 0x29, 0x3A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x73, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x66, 0x2E, 0x6C, 
0x61, 0x79, 0x6F, 0x75, 0x74, 0x2E, 0x6F, 0x70, 0x65, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x28, 0x4C, 
0x69, 0x76, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x52, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x42, 0x75, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x65, 0x72, 
0x4F, 0x70, 0x65, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x2E, 0x62, 0x6C, 0x5F, 0x69, 0x64, 0x6E, 0x61, 
0x6D, 0x65, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x61, 0x64, 0x64, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x5F, 0x6B, 
0x65, 0x79, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x70, 0x73, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x5B, 0x5D, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 
0x0A, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x20, 0x72, 0x65, 0x67, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x28, 0x29, 0x3A, 
0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x62, 0x70, 0x79, 0x2E, 0x75, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x73, 0x2E, 
0x72, 0x65, 0x67, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x5F, 0x63, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x28, 0x4C, 
0x69, 0x76, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x52, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x42, 0x75, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x65, 0x72, 
0x4F, 0x70, 0x65, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
0x20, 0x62, 0x70, 0x79, 0x2E, 0x74, 0x79, 0x70, 0x65, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x56, 0x49, 0x45, 0x57, 0x33, 
0x44, 0x5F, 0x4D, 0x54, 0x5F, 0x6F, 0x62, 0x6A, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x2E, 0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x65, 
0x6E, 0x64, 0x28, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x75, 0x5F, 0x66, 0x75, 0x6E, 0x63, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 
0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6D, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x62, 0x70, 0x79, 0x2E, 0x63, 0x6F, 
0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x2E, 0x77, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x64, 0x6F, 0x77, 0x5F, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x6E, 
0x61, 0x67, 0x65, 0x72, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x6B, 0x63, 0x20, 0x3D, 
0x20, 0x77, 0x6D, 0x2E, 0x6B, 0x65, 0x79, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x69, 0x67, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x61, 
0x64, 0x64, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x69, 0x66, 0x20, 0x6B, 0x63, 0x3A, 
0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x6B, 0x6D, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x77, 
0x6D, 0x2E, 0x6B, 0x65, 0x79, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x69, 0x67, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x61, 0x64, 0x64, 
0x6F, 0x6E, 0x2E, 0x6B, 0x65, 0x79, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x70, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x77, 0x28, 0x6E, 
0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x3D, 0x27, 0x4F, 0x62, 0x6A, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x6F, 0x64, 0x65, 
0x27, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x73, 0x70, 0x61, 0x63, 0x65, 0x5F, 0x74, 0x79, 0x70, 0x65, 0x3D, 0x27, 0x45, 
0x4D, 0x50, 0x54, 0x59, 0x27, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
0x6B, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x6B, 0x6D, 0x2E, 0x6B, 0x65, 0x79, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x70, 0x5F, 
0x69, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6D, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x77, 0x28, 0x4F, 0x62, 0x6A, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 
0x43, 0x75, 0x72, 0x73, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x41, 0x72, 0x72, 0x61, 0x79, 0x2E, 0x62, 0x6C, 0x5F, 0x69, 
0x64, 0x6E, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x27, 0x53, 0x50, 0x41, 0x43, 0x45, 0x27, 0x2C, 0x20, 
0x27, 0x50, 0x52, 0x45, 0x53, 0x53, 0x27, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x63, 0x74, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x3D, 0x54, 0x72, 
0x75, 0x65, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x73, 0x68, 0x69, 0x66, 0x74, 0x3D, 0x54, 0x72, 0x75, 0x65, 0x29, 0x0D, 
0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x61, 0x64, 0x64, 0x6F, 0x6E, 
0x5F, 0x6B, 0x65, 0x79, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x70, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x64, 0x28, 
0x28, 0x6B, 0x6D, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x6B, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x29, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x64, 0x65, 
0x66, 0x20, 0x75, 0x6E, 0x72, 0x65, 0x67, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x28, 0x29, 0x3A, 0x0D, 
0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x66, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x20, 0x6B, 0x6D, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x6B, 
0x6D, 0x69, 0x20, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x61, 0x64, 0x64, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x5F, 0x6B, 0x65, 0x79, 0x6D, 
0x61, 0x70, 0x73, 0x3A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x6B, 0x6D, 
0x2E, 0x6B, 0x65, 0x79, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x70, 0x5F, 0x69, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6D, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x72, 0x65, 
0x6D, 0x6F, 0x76, 0x65, 0x28, 0x6B, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x61, 
0x64, 0x64, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x5F, 0x6B, 0x65, 0x79, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x70, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x63, 0x6C, 0x65, 
0x61, 0x72, 0x28, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x62, 0x70, 0x79, 0x2E, 
0x75, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x73, 0x2E, 0x75, 0x6E, 0x72, 0x65, 0x67, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 
0x5F, 0x63, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x28, 0x4C, 0x69, 0x76, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x52, 0x6F, 0x6F, 
0x6D, 0x42, 0x75, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x65, 0x72, 0x4F, 0x70, 0x65, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x72, 
0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x62, 0x70, 0x79, 0x2E, 0x74, 0x79, 0x70, 0x65, 0x73, 
0x2E, 0x56, 0x49, 0x45, 0x57, 0x33, 0x44, 0x5F, 0x4D, 0x54, 0x5F, 0x6F, 0x62, 0x6A, 0x65, 0x63, 
0x74, 0x2E, 0x72, 0x65, 0x6D, 0x6F, 0x76, 0x65, 0x28, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x75, 0x5F, 0x66, 0x75, 
0x6E, 0x63, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x69, 0x66, 0x20, 0x5F, 0x5F, 0x6E, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 
0x5F, 0x5F, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x3D, 0x20, 0x22, 0x5F, 0x5F, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x5F, 0x5F, 0x22, 
0x3A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x72, 0x65, 0x67, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x28, 
0x29,
```

Space char code: 0x20, Tab char code: 0x09

The printscreen of the error: [The error in The Blender 2.78c-windows32 in the above script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpx1k.png)

Comment: It is more likely that your script contains the error. Can you include the error message in your question?

Comment: I have just added the printscreen of the error in my message above.

Comment: Please [post text, not screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3005167) of the error message. (Apart from that, the message is pretty clear - you mixed spaces and tabs in your script. [Don't do that!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5685816/3005167))

Comment: Well, the error says you have mixed spaces and tabs... that is a bad idea in Python, and usually an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)

Comment: I have just added the hex code of the file and it has not had a mixing of spaces and tabs.

Comment: Go to **Window > Console** (or something like that, I'm not on Windows) to see Blender's console, not the Python console. That will have your error message, not the console you have open in your screenshot.

Comment: I thank you. It is the best comment for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `ObjectCursorArray` does not exist - you use it in `kmi = km.keymap_items.new()`.

Python errors are printed to the [console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/introduction.html), you need to look there to see the error.

It is also possible to run a script within blender's python console and see the eror messages there. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51159/935) shows how and links to an addon that can make it easier.