# Load a file content to python grid GUI

Tags: python

I am not a developer, just a system admin, i have already written a python script to collect a bunch of network information to 4 files(1 file has 4 lines).

File content format:

```
Device A: Status OK
Devide B: Status Ok
Device C: Status OK
Devide D: Status  Failed
```

Now i hope somebody can help me to show the content of file to a grid(table) in python which 1 file to 1 one row and 1 columns is one line

P/s: I don't know about Python GUI programming so i just stop there and view file by manual

Thanks

Comment: can you post some examples? also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I will update my question for you

Comment: Here is a sample of the table which i want but i don't know how to load the content to it: https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/882126-grid-view-table-list-tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it worked for me-

*filename* contains **4** lines. It displays each line as a column in `r` number of rows.

Replace `r` by your number of files and input accordingly.

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()

#reading lines from the file
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('filename')]

for r in range(3):  #r-rows
    for c in range(4): #c-columns
        Tkinter.Label(root, text=lines[c],
                      borderwidth=1).grid(row=r, column=c)
root.mainloop()
```

Output -

[image]

**Update -**

for displaying headers -

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()

lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('filename')]

for r in range(4):
    for c in range(5):
        #0th row 0th column, leave it empty
        if c==0 and r==0:
            pass

        #non-0th row non-0th column, fill with values
        elif r!=0 and c!=0:
            Tkinter.Label(root, text=lines[c-1],
                     borderwidth=1).grid(row=r, column=c)

        else: 
            #0th column, meaning ROW headers
            if c==0:
                Tkinter.Label(root, text="row"+str(r),
                          borderwidth=1).grid(row=r, column=c)

            #0th row, meaning COLUMN headers
            if r==0:
                Tkinter.Label(root, text="column"+str(c),
                          borderwidth=1).grid(row=r, column=c)


root.mainloop()
```

Output -

[image]

Comment: Thank so much, but i need some row title and column title too. This table is so simple

Comment: Here is the one i hope to have https://bytes.com/attachments/attachment/2782d1267057367/entrygrid.gif

Comment: @ToiLee please check my updated answer. Kindly mark it as an answer if that helped :)

Comment: Thank you, how do it know which file to load ? i have 4 different file names

Comment: add the *filenames* in an array, and iterate over the *filenames* in an outermost `for` loop.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you, can you please accept it as an answer? Put green tick like this -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Hi, when i tried  elif c==0 and r==2:
                      ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation . Why was that ?

Comment: Thats a syntax error. Pls refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685816/5213405