# Django identation error in Except UserDoesNotExist

Tags: python

This is views.py file which show error:

[image: Image 1]

I'm also uploading the image which show what is the error:

[image: Image 2]

Comment: can you please share the code here instead of posting a picture? that way we would be able to check whether the indentation is proper or not

Comment: This question has been highly downvoted for several reasons: (1) the use of txtspk, which gives the impression the writer is unwilling to use a spell-checker; (2) poor formatting, which does not make the problem easy to read; (3) begging of volunteers, (4) [code presented in an image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Django issue.

The error message is clear about the problem:
`TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

It is not clear from the screenshot, but your editor should have a way to indicate whitespace characters in the background. This will let you see where you have a tab character.

Also, refer to this question: ["inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)