# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation - Integration MailChimp Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, mailchimp

I have just integrated `Mailchimp` to my Django Project using `Ajax`. The email address field is working properly and I'm able to get the email in both my Mailchimp list and my database. Now when I try to add a field that let a user add his first name to the form, I keep getting errors like this one for example: `from .utils import SendSubscribeMail
  File "C:\Users\locq\Desktop\Coding\SEARCH_APP\venv\src\search\utils.py", line 8
    self.fname = fname
                     ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`..

So how can I add a FNAME field and send the datas to mailchimp on submit?

Here's my code:

In my Settings.p I added my Mailchimp credentials at the bottom like this:

```
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = '767ba************-us6'
MAILCHIMP_SUBSCRIBE_LIST_ID = '45c*******'
```

I created a utils.py file to use Threading, the Mailchimp package and import my credentials from the settings:

```
import threading
import mailchimp
from django.conf import settings

class SendSubscribeMail(object):
    def __init__(self, email, fname):
        self.email = email
        self.fname = fname
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def run(self):
        API_KEY = settings.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
        LIST_ID = settings.MAILCHIMP_SUBSCRIBE_LIST_ID
        api = mailchimp.Mailchimp(API_KEY)
        try:
            api.lists.subscribe(LIST_ID, {'email': self.email}, merge_vars={'FNAME': self.fname}, double_optin=False)
        except:
            return False
```

Custom Def to get the input names:

```
def subscribe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.POST['fname_id']
        Subscribe.objects.create(fname_id = fname)
        email = request.POST['email_id']
        email_qs = Subscribe.objects.filter(email_id = email)
        if email_qs.exists():
            data = {"status" : "404"}
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            Subscribe.objects.create(email_id = email)
            SendSubscribeMail(email, fname) # Send the Mail, Class available in utils.py
    return HttpResponse("/")
```

The models.py I use to add the email (and fname) in the Subscribe table of my database:

```
class Subscribe(models.Model):
    email_id = models.EmailField()
    fname_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email_id
```

My html form:

```
<div class="signup subs-form">

  <div class="header">
    <p>Sign Up For Beta</p>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
  </div>

  <form method="POST" id="subscribe" class="subs-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
      <input type="email" class="button-" id="email" name="email_id" placeholder="E-mail">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" class="button-" id="fname" name="fname_id" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="submit" class="button-" id="submit" value="Join">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

And finally, here's the Ajax code I have at the bottom of my page:

```
  $('#subscribe').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var email_id = $("#email").val();
      if(email_id){
        var csrfmiddlewaretoken = csrftoken;
        var fname_id = $("#fname").val();
        var email_data = {"email_id": email_id,
                          "fname_id": fname_id,
                          "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : csrfmiddlewaretoken};
        $.ajax({
          type : 'POST',
          url :  '/subscribe/',
          data : email_data,
          success : function(response){
            $('#email').val('');
            if(response.status == "404"){
              alert("This Email is already been subscribed!");
            }
            else{
              alert("Thank you for Subscribing! Please Check your Email to Confirm the Subscription");
            }
          },
          error: function(response) {
            alert("Sorry Something went Wrong");
            $('#email').val('');
          }
        });
        return false;
      }
      else{
        alert("Please provide correct email!");
      }
  });


function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
})
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: As the error says, some of your lines use indentation with spaces, others with tabs, etc. and thus it is not consistent. It has nothing to do with mailchimp, ... itself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! And can I fix the indentation then?

Comment: you look to the code block, how the lines are indented and you harmonize those. For example put everything in spaces.

Comment: I don't understand, I have tried with spaces but I keep getting the error..

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5685406/67579).

Comment: Alright, this has been fixed using autopep8, now I just need to find out how to make the fname input work. Would you have any solutions fo this?

Comment: Nevermind It worked with the actual code, thanks for your help! I appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

According to the python documentation, python cannot mix tabs and spaces for indentation, and according to PEP-8, four spaces should be used for each indent level. When I attempt this it is true:

```py
>>> for i in range(20):
    'indent with tabs'
    'indent with spaces'

SyntaxError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

If you have a python IDE, not just writing them in, say Notepad or TextEdit, it should convert each tab to four spaces, or (not recommended because of PEP-8) every 4 four spaces to one tab.

Edit: you can use the `Ctrl+H` combination to find/replace each tab with 4 spaces (this will not affect your actual code; your tabs in strings should be `'\t'`)

Comment: Just tried out the new module, seems a lot better than the method I gave :)