# getting error in Sublime editor: Python code

Tags: python

Getting an error: "Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"
Please help to spot an error in my code for the sub that "If a word starts with a vowel (aeiou), add the letters 'yay'.  Example:  the word are would become areyay."

Error for line #5

```
def convertEnglishToPigLatin():
    print('You chose to convert English to PigLatin.')
    eng = input('Enter the English sentence to convert to PigLatin.\n')
    engWordSplit = eng.split()
    for i in range(0, len(engWordSplit)):  
        if engWordSplit[i].startswith(("a","A","e","E","i","I","o","O","u","U")):
            engWordSplit[i].append("yay")
        else:
            firstCharacter = engWordSplit.strip(0)
            engWordSplit.append(firstCharacter)
            engWordSplit.append("ay")
    print(engWordSplit)
```

Comment: hmmm, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation

Comment: lbragile: voila. this works! thank you so much.

Comment: Forgot to mention: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: i know. for now, i'm just following naming conventions as per examples from the 'master' (community college introduction to prog. teacher)

Comment: still a bit struggling with the code, but the original question was answered already. my current ugly code is as follows:

Comment: def convertEnglishToPigLatin():
    print('You chose to convert English to PigLatin.')
    eng = input('Enter the English sentence to convert to PigLatin.\n')
    engWordSplit = eng.split()
    for i in range(0, len(engWordSplit)):
     currentWord = engWordSplit[i]

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer by hitting the check mark to make it green 

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the following in sublime text editor:

> View => Indentation => Indent using spaces

This should convert all tabs to spaces and eliminate the error.

Comment: Alexander Cécile: Yes, it does. Thank you.

Comment: @kstatinet if my answer helped you, please consider upvoting and accepting it.