# Jupyter notebook tab or space indentation error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, indentation

```
# Convert string column to float
def str_column_to_float(dataset, column):
    for row in dataset:
        row[column] = float(row[column].strip())
        print(row[column])
```

Am trying to create a above function in python using jupyter notebook. But am getting error like below:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-b591f37367db>", line 5
    print(row[column])
                      ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There are whitespace characters on the line with `print(...` while tabs were used to indent the other lines, replace all  whitespace characters with tabs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError (or a TabError). How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-or-a-taberror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Advise that is slightly off topic: in your editor/IDE, enable viewing whitespace characters.  You will be able to catch the problem by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the spaces and indentations are proper. The code you have entered should look something like this: [image]