# Python "inconsistent use"

Tags: python, sorting

Sample from the file :

```
Employer: {
name:"Jack M", age:"213", phone:"11221"
}

Guest: {
name:"Alex K", age:"203", phone:"11111"
}
```

From that file, i need to export all the  Guest names. Tried that:

```
file = "data.txt"
nameslist=[]

with open(file, "r") as f:
    i = f.read()

check = i.find('Guest: {')
while check != -1:
    i = i.replace('Guest: {', '\n') 
    i = i.split('\n')
    i = i[1]
    i = i.replace('name:"', '\n') 
    i = i.split('\n')
    i = i.replace('",' '\n')
    i = i.split('\n')
    global nameslist
    nameslist.append(i[0])
    i = i[1]
    check = i.find('Guest: {')

print(nameslist)
```

always have an error like that:

```
  File "asd.py", line 11
    i = i.split('\n')
                    ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: why there is a global in the middle ? if the code is not a part of the function ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)

Answer (score 0):

With python3 you can only either use tabs or spaces at the beginning of a line to mark indentation. Use your editor of choice to search/highlight 'tabs' or ' '. Then, may be, it is the best idea to replace a tab four spaces (using the replace tool of your editor).

Answer (score 0):

> What i am doing wrong ?

Not reading the error message? It is reasonably clear: when indenting (leading space before the code), sometimes you're using spaces and sometimes you're using tab characters. You must use *either* one or the other (spaces is usually recommended in Python). And should configure your text editor such that it always uses the right one.