# How to solve inconsistent indentation in Notepad++

Tags: python, indentation, git-bash

I'm studying the basics of python and I'm having an indentation issue.
When I try to run a code on GitBash it gives me the error:

```
$ python organize_photos.py


File "organize_photos.py", line 7
    if place not in places:
                          ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

So i checked my code on Notepad++ and it is giving me some problem on line 7,

[image]

but to me the indentation looks fine, what could be the problem?

Comment: The error message is telling you that you're using tabs and spaces inconsistently in your indentation. Did you check your use of tabs and spaces?

Comment: how can i do this check?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't like a mixture of tabs and spaces. Personally I prefer to use spaces as they render the same on any system.
I see you're using Notepad++, you can head to `Settings > Preferences > Language > Tab Settings` and convert all tabs to spaces.