# How to manage 'inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation' across editors

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sublimetext3

I've been working with python for a while, and understand how to use tabs correctly, but recently in a project I have started working across Jupyter notebooks and Sublime. When I copy and paste code over, the indentation gets completely messed up. Usually it goes from tabs to 4 spaces and it doesn't like that so I have to manually change every line. It happens on occasion when I copy from one python file to another in just Sublime as well.

Is there some sort of general way, or just setting within those applications, that can prevent this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter Notebooks indent with 4 spaces by default. Not sure where you'd be getting tabs unless you originally copy-pasted tabs.

If you want to keep the tabs in SublimeText, select a Python file, go to "Preferences" --> "Settings - Syntax Specific" and add the line:

```
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false
```

Although, if your sources were already mixed (some cells in jupyter use tabs, some use spaces) then it's better to standardise on paste in sublime, and use:

```
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
```

Also, when you're pasting in SublimeText, instead of just Paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, use Paste & Indent: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Btw, Python3 recommends 4 spaces by default, almost as a standard. So maybe set that in your editor. Most of them have settings for "Tabs & Indents" somewhere with code formatting.