# Why can't i use print function just below for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, printing

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    new_list = []
    i = 0

    for a in elements:
        print(a)
        if i%2==0:
            new_list+=a
        i+=1

    return new_list

print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"])) # Should be ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
print(skip_elements(['Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Peach'])) # Should be ['Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Peach']
print(skip_elements([])) # Should be []
```

**This is Showing indentation error.Even this doesn't work when we place print(a) just before i+=1, whereas the below code works perfectly.Why so??**

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    new_list = []
    i = 0

    for a in elements:
        if i%2==0:
            new_list+=a
        i+=1
        print(a)

    return new_list

print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"])) # Should be ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
print(skip_elements(['Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Peach'])) # Should be ['Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Peach']
print(skip_elements([])) # Should be []
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: File "rough.py", line 6
    print(a)
           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Seems to be your editor issue, not python. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of using both tabs and spaces in the code, You can use an editor like Notepad++ to see the inconsistencies or and IDE like Pycharm to debug these issues easily. 
In Pycharm you can reformat your code by ctrl + shift + alt + l in Windows/Linux and cmd + shift + option + l in MacOS.

Answer (score -3):

Here should be :

```
new_list.append(a)
```

not:

```
new_list+=a
```

then 
[image: result]

Comment: Do not include screenshots in either questions or answers. Also, while you raised a valid concern, it does not address the OP's question.