# How to indent my python code using shell command

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I coded a few lines in python for some other activity but when I run the python script I always get `indentation error` or `TabError : inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`.

Is there any way to fix this using Unix command
without installing any `IDE` or `Pycharm`?

**Error below :**

> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Please show us some code. It will be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)

Answer (score 0):

The [`expand`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expand.1.html) utility replaces tabs with spaces. But you really want to configure your editor to indent Python code using only spaces instead.

Comment: Simply replacing tabs with spaces may not work if you already have a mix of the two, though.