# Join bytes into one string in python

Tags: python

I have the following function that sends a string from ESP32 to Raspberry:

```
def rx_and_echo():
    sock.send("\nsend anything\n")
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(buf_size)
        if data:
            print(data)
            sock.send(data)
```

The format received by Raspberry is as follow:

```
b'T'
b'e'
b'x'
b't'
```

How to convert it into just *Text*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: @Tomerikoo That doesn't join, does it?

Comment: Well `b't' + b'e'` gives `b'te'`...

Comment: Regarding your edit: That error seems quite easy to fix? Did you try fixing your indentations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5685406/6045800)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45621722/6045800)

Comment: Yes, tab error is fiexed. But it sends only the first letter

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the data Rx and keep pushing element by element instead of the list here:

```
lst = [b'T',b'e',b'x',b't']
x = ''.join([""+st.decode("utf-8") for st in lst])
sock.send(x)

#to have data as a list from socket
data_list = []
while True:
   data = sock.recv(buf_size)
   if data:
      #for certain length of data you want to accumulate and then send
      if len(data_list)>3:
         msg = ''.join([""+st.decode("utf-8") for st in data_list])
         sock.send(msg)
         data_list = []
      else:
         data_list.append(data)
```

Output:

```
Text
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this maybe?

```
def rx_and_echo():
    sock.send("\nsend anything\n")
    res = ''
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(buf_size)
        if data:
            res += data.decode()
    sock.send(res)
```

Edit:
Actually, that doesn't seem right. What exactly does sock.recv return?
Does this help?

```
def rx_and_echo():
    sock.send("\nsend anything\n")
    res = ''
    for b in sock.recv(buf_size)
        res += b.decode()
    sock.send(res)
```

Comment: Same, TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: TabError fixed, but it sends only first letter