# Solving Indentation Issues in Python: Tips and Tricks?

Tags: python

i have  aproblem with indent this code

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    #print(response.text)
    string=response.text
    #print(response.text)
    results = re.findall(r'<th scope="row">(.*?)</th>\n.*?<td>(.*?)</td>\n.*?<td>(.*?)</td>\n.*?<td>(.*?)</td>', string, re.DOTALL)
    for t in results:
    print(t)
else:
    print("Errore nella richiesta, codice di stato:", response.status_code)
```

i think is correct but return me error
File "/home/stefano/Desktop/test.py", line 68
print(t)
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

i try to reduce tab and use space but  return error again

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    #print(response.text)
    string=response.text
    #print(response.text)
    results = re.findall(r'<th scope="row">(.*?)</th>\n.*?<td>(.*?)</td>\n.*?<td>(.*?)</td>\n.*?<td>(.*?)</td>', string, re.DOTALL)
    for t in results:
    print(t)
else:
    print("Errore nella richiesta, codice di stato:", response.status_code)
```

i hope one day everyone create a fork of python without indentation Hell

Comment: how is your editor configured? the standard is to use spaces instead of tabs, so if your editor introduces 4 spaces every time you press tab button you should not have any problem. Any modern code editor has this option

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the if statement there is a for loop which has no indentation. The correct code should be:

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    #print(response.text)
    string=response.text
    #print(response.text)
    results = re.findall(r'<th scope="row">(.*?)</th>\n.*?<td>(.*?)</td>\n.*?<td>(.*?)</td>\n.*?<td>(.*?)</td>', string, re.DOTALL)
    for t in results:
        print(t)
else:
    print("Errore nella richiesta, codice di stato:", response.status_code)
```

Comment: yea work @Marcello Zago thanks so much

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki i use Geany and in preferences --> editor  --->indentation  i have  width 4   type:  tabs and spaces , auto indentmode  current chars  tabkey indents flagged

Comment: @ernestogevara If it works, think about accepting the answer. And another tip I can give you is to always check whether your IDE/ text editor shows you an error. Or to read your errors carefully to find the line where your error occurs.